# Source convert does not respect report folder hierarchy

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm working with `sfdx force:source:convert` to convert to metadata format for Reports and Report Folders

My folder in source format is:

- reports/

  - Top/

    - report1.report-meta.xml
    - Middle/

      - report2.report-meta.xml
      - Bottom/

        - report3.report-xml.xml
      - Bottom.reportFolder-meta.xml
    - Middle.reportFolder-meta.xml
  - Top.reportFolder-meta.xml

But after conversion, the output is not hierarchical, it is flattened to the top level:

- reports/

  - Top.meta-xml
  - Middle.meta-xml
  - Bottom.meta-xml
  - Top/

    - report1.report
  - Middle/

    - report2.report
  - Bottom/

    - report3.report

Am I missing something? I would have expected it to respect the hierarchical structure upon conversion.

Comment: what version are you on?

Comment: API version 52.0 @KrisGoncalves

Comment: apologies, I meant the `sfdx -v`.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves no, my apologies - `sfdx-cli/7.113.0 darwin-x64 node-v14.17.1`

Comment: The report hierarchy was retained when converting on my end (copied from your question) even when on your version. That was with me specifying the path to reports and an output directory `sfdx force:source:covert -r reportPath -d outputDir`. I know there's been [issues](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWcfQAG) around nested folders before so not sure if it's just something different on your end that leads to this behavior?

Comment: Thats very odd, i used the exact same command. Thanks for looking, I will take a look at the issues link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I cannot get the folder structure to mirror that of the original source structure, if the reports specify the `folderName` within their source file, then they do at least deploy correctly, as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm):

> Name of the folder that houses the report.

e.g.

```
<folderName>Top</folderName> <!-- in report1 -->
<folderName>Top/Middle</folderName> <!-- in report2 -->
<folderName>Top/Middle/Bottom</folderName> <!-- in report3 -->
```